# Not being able to register a user to shared roster group to my ejabberd server using php script

Tags: php, api, ejabberd, multiuserchat, ejabberd-server

I have a few departments in our workplace. Whenever we register a new employee, we need to register this employee to this department so that all other members in the department can see him/her and also chat with him/her.

What should be the best way to do this? should I use MUC or shared roster groups. I want to do this using a php's script.. how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Gow to ejabberd's WebAdmin -> your vhost -> Shared Roster Groups -> and create a group "department1", with Displayed groups: department1.

Then, you can add accounts to that group by calling this command, for example:

```
$ ejabberdctl srg_user_add user1 localhost department1 localhost
```

Try this, check it works as you want, and later you can see how to call this command using PHP. If you enable ejabberd_xmlrpc you can make XML-RPC queries to ejabberd. Or if you install mod_rest (from ejabberd-contrib git repository), you can use ReST calls.

Comment: when u say account, i am assuming users. in the field user1 do i have to give the full address JID: user1@domain.com or only user1? and leave localhost as it is , right?

Comment: secondly how do i enable ejabberd_xmlrpc?

Comment: when i click on the department 1, a form opens up with four fields: Name, description, members, Displayed Group- is there any guide as to exactly what should be inserted here. I know the name will be Department 1, description depert 1 members, Displayed Group: Department 1 ( as per your suggestion ) and what should I put in the field members? can i put only one member here or multiple members, what are the delimiters to separate memebrs? sorry if these questions are very stupid.

Comment: Technically speaking, a user is a human being, you can't add a user ;) What you can add is an account, that a user can use to chat. And that account is identified with a JID formed by username@host, in my example it is user1@localhost, in your case maybe it is pheludar@mycompany.com or whatever.

Comment: For ejabberd_xmlrpc see example configuration in https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/managing/#restrict-execution-with-accesscommands or maybe there are tutorials and other examples in internet.

Comment: If you created the group department1, then in Displayed groups put department1.
In members put nothing, as you will later add members with the srg_user_add command calls.

Comment: Thanks. I have done that in the admin panel. I will try the command line code and see what happens, whether the users acn see each other or not.

Comment: RECV: admin@localhost/xmpphp  [INFO]: Bound to admin@localhost/xmpphp  [VERBOSE]:  [VERBOSE]: SENT:  [VERBOSE]: Successfully sent 104 bytes.  [VERBOSE]: RECV:  [INFO]: Session started  [DEBUG]: EVENT: session_start [VERBOSE]: Socket is ready; send it.  [VERBOSE]: SENT: phptest phpt1st  [VERBOSE]: Successfully sent 316 bytes. [VERBOSE]: Disconnecting...  [VERBOSE]: Socket is ready; send it.  [VERBOSE]: SENT: [VERBOSE]: Successfully sent 16 bytes. [VERBOSE]: RECV: phptestphpt1stAccess denied by service policy  [DEBUG]: EVENT: new_user_registered  [VERBOSE]: RECV:  [DEBUG]: EVENT: end_stream